# How do I list all the top-level folders in given GCS bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I start with

```
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

    <what's next? Need something like client.list_folders(path)>
```

I know how to:

1. list all the blobs (including blobs in sub-sub-sub-folders, of any depth) with `bucket.list_blobs()`
2. or how to list all the blobs recursively in given folder with `bucket.list_blobs(prefix=<path to subfolder>)`

but what if my file system structure has `100` top level folders, each having thousands of files. Any efficient way to get only those `100` top level folder names without listing all the inside blobs?

Comment: Yes, by only processing the `prefixes` returned. I do not have an example to post. Google Cloud Storage uses `prefix` and `separator` to facilitate listing objects. Hopefully, this tip will help you.

Comment: @JohnHanley excellent tip regarding "`prefixes`". This won't load however until you iterate list_blobs first element. PS it's actually `delimiter` not `separator` on GCS but we know what you mean.

Comment: Official documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can get the **100 top level folders** without listing all the inside blobs. Google Cloud Storage does not have folders or subdirectories, the library just creates an illusion of a hierarchical file tree.

I used this simple code :

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs('my-project')
res = []

for blob in blobs:
   if blob.name.split('/')[0] not in res:
       res.append(blob.name.split('/')[0]) 

print(res)
```

Comment: "Google Cloud Storage does not have folders or subdirectories" -> that what I thought as well. thanks!

Comment: This is not true - you missed the `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: Please add a working solution for this case if my statement is not true

Comment: Not true. It can be done without listing all the inside blobs.

Comment: Without using `delimiter` argument, this can be very inefficient. Also, the OP's question was how to list _directories_ only, and that can be done using:

`if not isinstance(blob, str)`

(Also, checking if the name is already in `res` is a bit superfluous, because you can't have multiple folders with the same name.)

Answer (score 11):

All the response here have a piece of the answer but you will need to combine: the `prefix`, the `delimiter` and the `prefixes` in a loaded `list_blobs(...)` iterator. Let me throw down the code to get the 100 top level folders and then we'll walk through it.

```
import google.cloud.storage as gcs
client = gcs.Client()
blobs = client.list_blobs(
    bucket_or_name=BUCKET_NAME, 
    prefix="", 
    delimiter="/", 
    max_results=1
)
next(blobs, ...) # Force list_blobs to make the api call (lazy loading)
# prefixes is now a set, convert to list
print(list(blobs.prefixes)[:100])
```

In first eight lines we build the GCS client and make the `client.list_blobs(...)` call. In your question you mention the `bucket.list_blobs(..)` method - as of version 1.43 this still works but [the page on Buckets in the docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html) say this is now deprecated. The only difference is the keword arg `bucket_or_name`, on line 4.

We want folders at the top level, so we don't actually need to specify `prefix` at all, however, it will be useful for other readers to know that if you had wanted to list folders in a top-level directory `stuff` then you should specify a trailing slash. This kwarg would then become `prefix="stuff/"`.

Someone already mentioned the `delimiter` kwarg, but to iterate, you should specify this so GCS knows how to interpret the blob names as directories. Simple enough.

The `max_results=1` is for efficiency. Remember that we don't want blobs here, we want only folder names. Therefore if we tell GCS to stop looking once it finds a single blob, it might be faster. In practice, I have not found this to be the case but it could easily be if you have vast numbers of blobs, or if the storage is cold-line or whatever. YMMV. Consider it optional.

The `blobs` object returned is an lazy-loading iterator, which means that it won't load - including not even populating its members - until the first api call is made. To get this first call, we ask for the `next` element in the iterator. In your case, you know you have at least one file, so simply calling `next(blobs)` will work. It fetches the blob that is next in line (at the front of the line) and then throws it away.

However, if you could not guarantee to have at least one blob, then `next(blobs)`, which needs to return something from the interator, will raise a `StopIteration` exception. To get round this, we put the default value of the ellipsis `...`.

Now the member of `blobs` we want, `prefixes`, is loaded, we print out the first 100. The output will be something like:

```
{'dir0/','dir1/','dir2/', ...}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. Just a note, when I tried this exact code I got `TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable` for `blobs.prefixes[:100]`, so it seems like `prefixes` is now a set. No big deal, since the results could just be converted to a list. I couldn't find anything in the docs specifying why this has changed.

Comment: @Flobbinhood thanks for the pointer, I have updated my code with your suggestion. Hero!

Comment: Be careful, in my GCP bucket the proposed method can give different number of results when changing `max_results` param to a higher number. And it has nothing to do with limiting the output to 100.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the top-level prefixes by using a delimited listing. See the [list_blobs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client.list_blobs) documentation:

> delimiter (str) – (Optional) Delimiter, used with prefix to emulate
>   hierarchy.

Something like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
storage_client.list_blobs(BUCKET_NAME, delimiter='/')
```

Comment: For me your code is not working, this is what works: storage_client.list_blobs('my-bucket', prefix='source/',delimiter='/'),

Comment: @marian.vladoi - are you saying that `delimiter` doesn't work without a `prefix`? That should not be the case.

Comment: doesn't work for me, somehow still lists all the blobs in the subdirectory. The documentation that you posted is also very vague.