# How to list objects of one depth level without listing sub-objects by GCP Cloud Storage Python API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

The Cloud Storage Python API allows to list objects using prefix, which limits the listing to certain sub-branches of objects in the bucket.

```
bucket_name = "my-bucket"
folders = "logs/app"
storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=folders)
```

This operations will return all objects which names start from "logs/app". But it will return absolutely all objects, including those which lay on deeper levels of hierarchy. For example, I've got many applications `app=1`, `app=2`, etc. So that the output will be like this:

```
logs/app=1
logs/app=1/module=1
logs/app=1/module=1/log_1.txt
logs/app=1/module=1/log_2.txt
logs/app=2
logs/app=2/module=1
logs/app=2/module=1/log_1.txt
logs/app=2/module=1/log_2.txt
```

and etc.
This operation of listing objects as it is mentioned above is scanning everything and because of that it's slow. For example, if I've got 80K or 1M files stored in those folders, all of them will be scanned and returned.

I would like to get only result only for one depth level. For example, I would like to get only this:

```
logs/app=1
logs/app=2
```

And I don't want the SDK to scan everything. Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe not with this API, maybe there is another Python SDK which could be used for this?

Comment: Have you checked this? [How do I list all the top-level folders in given GCS bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526251/how-do-i-list-all-the-top-level-folders-in-given-gcs-bucket). Running `gsutil ls gs://path` command is an alternative.

Comment: Because folders do no exist on Cloud Storage, "depth" means nothing. That's why you haven't API for that unmeaningful concept. You have to get all the objects and filter on the name that you wish (or "depth" i.e. the number of / that you want in the object name

Comment: I don't agree that depth means nothing. I know that GCS uses the prefix concept, but if you look at the UI then the concept of folders (creating folders, uploading folders etc.) is clearly referenced and I don't think its unreasonable to expect a utility method for this and I don't think it's 'unmeaningful'. Whether that can be achieved technically is another matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Python API of cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest) does not have a built-in method to list objects at a specific depth level. But as @[Dharmaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273852/how-to-list-objects-of-one-depth-level-without-listing-sub-objects-by-gcp-cloud#comment132827299_75273852) pointed out in comments the accepted answer with that corresponding thread would achieve this by filtering the returned results after listing all objects.

I may have just made the for-loop compact to 1 liner in this answer.

As top level folders consist only 1 `/` we can filter that accordingly. But this just filters the folders and gives only the objects that are at the desired depth level. In this case for the top level it will be `/`. So try the following:

```
bucket_name = "my-bucket"
folders = "logs/app"
results = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=folders) #Note: [1]
required_objects = [blob for blob in results if '/' not in blob.name[len(folders):]]
```

1] At this point it will return absolutely all objects, including those which lay on deeper levels of hierarchy. Then we are just filtering ahead.

For more information go through [list_blobs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.client.Client#google_cloud_storage_client_Client_list_blobs) which returns an iterator used to find blobs in the bucket.